# How can I prevent a file (.json) to be commited with a git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

**How can I prevent a file (.json) to be commited with a git hook ?**

I have a .json which is on the server yet. So I can not use an gitignore. But now I do not want to allow anyone to change this file (commit it) because it would break something. I want to use a local hook.

How can I even get the special file in the commit ?

Could you please give me an instruction how to achieve this ?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: You want to prevent the autogenerated file or code file to be  commited?

Comment: No sorry it is a bit complicated to explain. I want that the hook checks if a special file will be commited and abort the commit it if the file is in the commit.

Comment: yes its possible to do.  You can write pre-commit hook rule, which will be triggered during commit and remove the file if it exist and then it will commit.

Comment: do you have an example for me ? That would be very nice.

Comment: if you written some code then I can say what's wrong with that.  However this link can give you some insight: https://jakemccrary.com/blog/2015/05/31/use-git-pre-commit-hooks-to-stop-unwanted-commits/. this is about unwanted commits but you can get some inspiration from that.

Comment: okay thank you ! I did not now how to do it all so I will now begin to write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `pre-commit` sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

ipath="foo/bar.json"
git diff --cached --name-only | if grep -qE "^$ipath$";then
    git reset HEAD -- "$ipath"
    echo "Warning: $ipath is removed from the index. It's not allowed to be committed."
fi
```

`git diff --cached --name-only` lists all the changed files that are going to be committed. If `foo/bar.json` is found in the list, then `git reset HEAD -- foo/bar.json` removes it from the index so that it's not committed but left in the working tree.

It works fine for you. However you can't ensure it does for others. For example, other contributors may delete it from their local repositories. What you need is a `pre-receive` hook in the central repository, the one on the server side. It rejects any push if the incoming commits touch `foo/bar.json`.

A `pre-receive` sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

ipath="foo/bar.json"
zero="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

while read old new name;do
    if [ "$zero" == "$old" ];then
        #creating new ref, do something here
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$zero" == "$new" ];then
        #deleting a ref, do something here
        continue
    fi

    #updating a ref, check if the incoming commits touch `foo/bar.json`
    git diff $old..$new --name-only | if grep -qE "^$ipath$";then
        c=$(git log $old..$new --pretty=%H -- $ipath)
        echo "Error: $ipath is changed in:"
        echo $c
        echo "Error: $ipath is not allowed to be committed and pushed."
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

The contributors receive the error message after `git push`. They must amend their commits and remove the changes of `foo/bar.json` before another try. In `pre-receive`, you need to deal with `deleting a ref` and `creating a ref` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that the server side does not support it. So I have to do it locally. But the first part will do it for me locally right ?